# How to name a single function-parameter-pack?

Tags: c++, parameters, clang, iso, pack

The question is simple - I wasn't able to find a better example in the ISO C++ documentation then this:

```
template<class ... targs> void func(targs ... args);
```

But even for it I wasn't able to find a satisfying explanation. And this is not what I'm looking for as I don't care for the argument types.

I want to write something like this:

```
void func(auto ... args)
{
    func1(args...); //here 'args' to be expanded
}
```

But the above or other similar representations won't compile under Clang.

Any ideas why and how can it be done? Also a quote from the latest ISO C++ standard will be welcome too.

What I want to do is implementing 'new' operator behavior by my own function and for this I need to pass constructor arguments with variable size, something like this:

```
struct x_new
{
    template<class T>
    inline T *allocate(... arg)
    {
        return new T(arg...);
    }
};
```

Which won't compile under Clang for now and I don't know why.

Comment: clang has no problems with `template<class ... targs> void func(targs ... args);`. And it happily accepts the body you've written for it too. What exactly is your question?

Comment: This is not a single named parameter pack but something else. What is it? Also why I can't write the second one?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Can you show how you want to use your function? What problem are you actually trying to solve? Related reading: [What is the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: You seem to somehow confuse a template function with variadic arguments (which is really a whole number of functions, instantiated depending on what you call the function with) and C-style varargs. You also seem to make some funny assumptions on `auto`. Note that `auto` is no such thing as "magic type removal", it has very clear (and strict) rules. If you write `auto`, the compiler needs a means to derive the correct type, which isn't the case here.

Comment: "named parameter pack" is not a standard term and I have no idea what you mean by it. `args` is a parameter pack, and it looks named to me, so why isn't it a named parameter pack? As for what's wrong with the second, clang's message seems clear to me: you just can't have parameters declared `auto`.

Comment: If I understand your intent, what you want is something like: `template<typename... args>void func(args...) { func2(std::forward(args...)); }` ?

Comment: I updated my OP to shows my indent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using normal template parameter packs like usual? Like e.g.

```
template<typename T, typename... argsT>
T *allocate(argsT... args)
{
    return new T(std::forward<argsT>(args)...);
}
```

Comment: Better yet, use `std::forward`. But yeah, this use of parameter packs is right. Worth noting might be that calling `allocate<T>` still allows `argsT` to be deduced from the actual arguments, it doesn't specify a fixed-but-empty set for the pack.

Comment: The way to use `std::forward` is `std::forward<argsT>(args)...`. You need to specify the template argument because it cannot be meaningfully deduced from `args`, as they will always be lvalues. The `...` needs to be outside the invocation because you need `std::forward` to be called for each parameter. It will appear to work okay so long as you only have a single parameter, but will break if you have more, or if you have none.

Comment: @hvd Thanks, I'm not fully up to date with all the new stuff yet.

Comment: Also I would like a citation from the ISO C++ standard which explains what is this and why my second example is invalid.